# Python How to add all values in a 2d Dictionary and return a single dictionary with summed values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Part of the program I am developing has a `2D dict` of length n.

**Dictionary Example:**

```
test_dict = {
0: {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 5}, 
1: {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}, 
2: {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}, 
3: {'A': 4, 'B': 2, 'C': 5}
}
```

All of the dictionaries have the same keys but different values. I need to sum all the values as to equal below.

I have tried to merge the dictionaries using the following:

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in test_dict.items():
    new_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

I also tried using:

```
new_dict = {**test_dict[0], **test_dict[1], **test_dict[2], **test_dict[3]}
```

Unfortuntly I have not had any luck in getting the desired outcome.

**Desired Outcome:** `outcome = {'A': 10, 'B': 5, 'C': 13}`

How can I add all the values into a single dictionary?

Comment: Not without what you've tried?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter` to simplify your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution using `pandas`**

Convert your `dict` to `pandas.DataFrame` and then do summation on columns and convert it back to `dict`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict, orient='index')
print(df.sum().to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'A': 10, 'B': 5, 'C': 13}
```

**Alternate solution**

Use `collections.Counter` which allows you to add the values of same keys within `dict`

```
from collections import Counter

d = Counter()    
for _,v in test_dict.items():
    d.update(v)

print(d)
```

Comment: @D.Morrissey Welcome. I have added alternate solution too. Hope you find that helpful too